# Google Maps: How to zoom out to all locations on map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am developing am app that shows a list of different places using google maps, i have everything working fine and working with currentLocation and the closestsLocation and it zooms to show this, but I have tried to change this to set it so that it zooms out to show all the buildings and not just the closest one

EDIT: this is the working code

```
// Sets the bounds of the map to include at lease one visable marker
function setBounds(){
if ( markerCluster.getMarkers().length > 0 && homeMarker != null){
    map.setZoom(17);
    var visableMarkers = markerCluster.getMarkers();
    // want to set the starting position at the homeMarker

    //Make an array of the LatLng's of the markers you want to show
    var LatLngList = new Array ();
    LatLngList.push(homeMarker.position);
    $.each(visableMarkers, function() {
        LatLngList.push(this.position);    
    });

    //  Create a new viewpoint bound
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
    //  Go through each...
    for (var i = 0, LtLgLen = LatLngList.length; i < LtLgLen; i++) {
        //  And increase the bounds to take this point
        bounds.extend (LatLngList[i]);
    }
    //  Fit these bounds to the map
    map.fitBounds (bounds); 
}
}
```

Comment: What do you have in the console? For example you have syntax error in the line: `var LatLngList = array`

Comment: no, im getting no error, it is just zooming to the middle of the markers but its zooming way too far in so you do not see all the markers

Comment: it seems like you are using markerCluster.  are you sure it isn't clurstered?

Comment: when you click on the cluster do you see the two LatLng you pushed within the bounds?

Comment: yes they are there, ive added them in the edit

Comment: you only push two coordinates onto the bounds.  how many total were you expecting to see?

Comment: i no ya, i sorted the problem, all i had to do was push all the co-ordinates into an array and use those to set the zoom... i have edited my question to show the working code

Answer (score 2):

The code for your array `LatLngList` is incorrect, I think it should say

```
var LatLngList = new Array (new google.maps.LatLng (52.537,-2.061), new google.maps.LatLng (52.564,-2.017));
```

Comment: ah yes, fixed this but all it is doing now is zooming into a spot in england away from everything!